# Laravel model creation fields dynamic

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

Here my code :

```
            $context = new Context;
            $context->name = 'blabla';
            if($original_lang === 'en') {
                $context->en = $sentence;
            } else if($original_lang === 'fr') {
                $context->fr = $sentence;
            } else if($original_lang === 'ja') {
                $context->ja = $sentence;
            }
            $context->save;
```

I think the part with original lang is redundant, anyone know a best way to write this ? thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write as below

```
 $context->{$original_lang} = $sentence;
```